# FreeBSD mount failed with error: operation not supported by device

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd, mount, virtualbox-guest-additions

I'm using freeBSD on VirtualBox on Windows10.
I want to mount on Windows. (HOST:Windows  GUEST:freeBSD)
I run mount command but got an error below.

```
mount -t vboxvfs -w mp /mnt/vbox
mount: mp: Operation not supported by device
```

How can I solve this error?

What I did:

I install `virtualbox-ose-additions-nox11-5.2.34` and `virtualbox-ose-kmod-5.2.34`,
then append `vboxguest_enable="YES"` and `vboxservice_enable="YES"` to my `/etc/rc.config`.

mp is normal empty folder on C:

I also install `Guest Additions` following Virtualbox's dialog.

Comment: Is `mp` a shared folder on the host system?

Comment: thank you for comment. I set pm as shared folder on virtualbox menu `device > shared folder > shared folder config > add`. and set params like this `path:C:/path/to/pm, folder_name:pm, auto_mount:true, mount_point:pm, is_parmanent:true`. Is it enough to make pm a shared folder? I'm not familiar to mount.

Comment: I am not familiar with VirtualBox on Windows10, but I was thinking that you may need to tell Windows to share the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error caused by typo.

wrong  : vboxfs
correct: vboxvfs

(I write correct command in this Question but I enter wrong command to my machine.)